# Limit Entity Reference to Only Display Content Created By User

Tags: entities

This might be an easy solution, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a content type referencing another content type. I have the entity reference field in the cotent type, and wish to limit the display to only show cotent from the other content type that the user has created. Right now, it is displaying all the content created from the other content type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a view to return only the content by the current user and then use that as the entity field reference.

You can select this form **ENTITY SELECTION**

[image]